# Does Visual Studio 2012 automatically converts currency?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm following a book on C# (Head's First C#) and came across a strange situation.

There are exercises where you build an event planner program for a dinner and birthday party, using Windows Forms. And the exercises make use of decimal types, with value ending with **M**. Being aware that this final letter means **Money**, the final calculation that my program was returning were different from the book.

For example, in a birthday party with 10 people, fancy decorations and a *Happy Birthday Myrtle* written in the cake, the book showed a result of $435.25, whereas for me, it showed R$570.25.

570.25 divided by 435.25 is 1.27~ approximately. But the dollar quotation is about R$2.70 today.

So, why my result is different? Does Visual Studio converts the monetary value for an old quotation or my program is making wrong calculations?

**Edited: this is the projec** http://www.mediafire.com/download/apg85nceod3n2g4/EventPlanner.zip

Comment: What's the result if you put this in front of your code: `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");`?

Comment: C# does not have a `Money` type. It has a `decimal` type, and `decimal` literals have the suffix `m`.

Comment: ...and the `m` doesn't stand for "money". It's the fifth letter in the word "decimal" (the first was taken by `double`).

Comment: @CoryNelson They taught me wrong, then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a problem with your code. The language will not automatically convert currencies. That would be silly *and* dangerous.

Comment: and to state the obvious, @epiplon, if you want more help, please show your code. A complete (but small!) example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, I thinked that the code wasn't a concern for the subject, in this specific case. I'm sorry.